# Structure of $\mathbb{F}^*_p$ and group automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $p,q$ be distinct primes. Prove that the map $f: \mathbb{F}^*_p \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^*_p$ defined by $f(x)=x^q$ is an automorphism if and only if $\gcd(p-1,q)=1$. I proved it using primitive root.

Q1) Is there any pure algebraic proof that avoid primitive root?

Q2) Is it true that the equation $x^q \equiv 1 \pmod p$ has either q solutions or 1 solution? Why? Why can't it has 4 solutions or like 16 solutions?

Comment: Q1 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337002

Answer (score 1):

As to Q1, it's a very general fact, which has been discussed several times on MSE. If $G$ is an abelian group of order $n$, then a map $\varphi: x \mapsto x^{k}$ is an endomorphism of $G$, and it is an automorphism if and only if $(n, k) = 1$.

The first part is clear, as in an abelian group $(xy)^{k} = x^{k} y^{k}$. As to the second part, note that if $(n, k) = 1$ then there are $u, v$ such that $1 = n u + v k$, so for $a \in G$ we have $a = a^{1} = a^{n u + v k} = (a^{v})^{k}$, so $\varphi$ has inverse $x \mapsto x^{v}$. If $(n, k) \ne 1$, then take for instance a prime $p \mid (n, k)$. Now $G$ has an element $b$ of order $p$, and $b^{k} = 1$, so $\varphi$ is not injective.

As to Q2, of course $1$ is always a solution. If there is a solution $a \ne 1$, then $a$ is an element of order $q$ in $\Bbb{F}_{p}^{\star}$, so $1, a, a^{2}, \dots, a^{q-1}$ are distinct solutions.

Comment: thank you! But in Q2, if $a \not= 1$ is a solution, doesn't it means order of $a$ divides $q$? why this implies $ord (a)=q$?

Comment: oic! because $q$ is a prime! thank you very much andreas :)

Comment: @spartan, yes! And you're welcome.